# Redis client blocks firebase listeners in Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redis

I'm working in a service that uses Firebase SDK Admin (Java). It used to work fine until I added a Redis client (Jedis) to manage queues. Since that change, my firebase listeners stop working. I don't have any error.

**Firebase Listener** - Admin SDK for Java

```
LOGGER.info("1. Se inicio la sesion de firebase.");
  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  listenerRef = database.getReference(ENVIRONMENT);
  DatabaseReference checkinRef = listenerRef.child(EFirebaseField.CHECKINS.getField());
  DatabaseReference collectRef;

  LOGGER.info("2. Carga de listeners de checkin para registro en base de datos.");

  checkinRef.orderByChild(EFirebaseField.STATUS.getField())
      .equalTo(EStatusFirebase.STARTED.getField())
      .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          LOGGER.debug("Se elimino un checkin STARTED: {} {}", dataSnapshot.getKey(),
              dataSnapshot.getRef());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
          LOGGER.debug("Se reubico un checkin STARTED: {} {}", dataSnapshot.getKey(),
              dataSnapshot.getRef());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
          LOGGER.debug("Se modifico un checkin STARTED: {} {}", dataSnapshot.getKey(),
              dataSnapshot.getRef());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
          LOGGER.info("A. Se agrego un nuevo checkin STARTED: {} {}", dataSnapshot.getKey(),
              dataSnapshot.getRef());
          firebaseActuators.processCheckin(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
          LOGGER.error("Ocurrio un error en checkin STARTED: {}", error.getMessage());
        }
      });
```

**Redis Client** - Jedis Client

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"${propertiesDir:}/database-${envTarget:dev}.properties"})

public class RedisConfig {
private static final Logger LOGGER_REDIS = LogManager.getLogger(RedisConfig.class);

@Value("${redis.url}")
private String redisUrl;

@Value("${redis.port}")
private int redisPort;

@Value("${redis.pw}")
private String redisPw;

@Value("${redis.maxTotal}")
private int maxTotal;

@Value("${redis.maxIdle}")
private int maxIdle;

@Value("${redis.minIdle}")
private int minIdle;

@Value("${redis.ssl.trustStore}")
private String trustStore;
@Value("${redis.ssl.trustStoreType}")
private String trustStoreType;
@Value("${redis.ssl.trustStorePassword}")
private String trustStorePassword;
@Value("${redis.ssl.keyStore}")
private String keyStore;
@Value("${redis.ssl.keyStorePassword}")
private String keyStorePassword;
@Value("${redis.ssl.keyStoreType}")
private String keyStoreType;

@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
try {

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", trustStoreType);
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);     
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", keyStoreType);

  JedisConnectionFactory cf = new JedisConnectionFactory(jedisPoolConfig());
  cf.setHostName(redisUrl);
  cf.setPort(redisPort);
  cf.setUseSsl(true);
  cf.setUsePool(true);
  cf.afterPropertiesSet();
  return cf;
} catch (RedisConnectionFailureException e) {
  LOGGER_REDIS.error("Error de conexion con Redis:" + e.getMessage(), e);
  return null;
}
}

@Bean
public JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig() {
  JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
  jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);
  jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
  jedisPoolConfig.setMinIdle(minIdle);
  jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
  jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
  jedisPoolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
  jedisPoolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(
      Duration.ofSeconds(60).toMillis());

  jedisPoolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(
      Duration.ofSeconds(30).toMillis());
  jedisPoolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
  jedisPoolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);

  return jedisPoolConfig;
 }

 @Bean
 public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
 RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();

 if (null == connectionFactory) {
    LOGGER_REDIS.error("Redis template service is not available");
    return null;
 };

 template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
 template.afterPropertiesSet();

 return template;
 }
```

¿Is there any problem if I have more than one kind of listener when I'm using firebase listeners? ¿Or maybe, my redis config have some problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem actually is not either Redis or Firebase, instead is the Truststore being set on the System.setProperties. Redis sets the trustore on the JVM and when Firebase tries to read the truststore, recognizes the one from Redis. That's the reason why you are having problems. Either is that or you have a problem with the configuration of your Beans. Regards.